# How to parse XML tags with dots in JavaScript/extJS

Tags: java, javascript, extjs

Dot in XML tag

I have problem with tags in xml file.

I have a lot of tags with dots for example `<tag.state>` example text `</tag.state>`

JavaScript (extJS), does not parse successfully tags with dots :\

XML file were generated automaticly, and I cannot influance in generated tags.. so is It possible to avoid this issue?

in cannot read tags in extJS

try with ' and dobule quatas " but also it fails...

fields: [ 'tag.state']

or

fields: [ "tag.state"]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in java where my xml file could only have `<string-array>` and `<item>` and `<name>` etc.  I just made a java file that ran through my xml (copied into a .txt) and rewrote everything with correct tags.  I can share it with you if you would like.

Comment: would you like to send me your Java code to solve this problem?